# Getting invalid command name in my Tkinter app

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run my application , its supposed to play an mp3 file when the current time is equal to one of times in a list. The mp3 file is in the same folder as my python file. However, Three  things happen. First, the sound doesn't play even though the time is correct and an output is shown in the terminal indicating that the time comparison is true. Second, an extra tkinter window pops up and finally, when I  try to close both of the windows, I get these errors:

```
time to pray at 03:10 PM
invalid command name "2184036301640calc_countdown"
    while executing
"2184036301640calc_countdown"
    ("after" script)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\My stuff\mypython\Tkinter\azan caller\azan_caller.py", line 266, in <module>
    call_azan()
  File "d:\My stuff\mypython\Tkinter\azan caller\azan_caller.py", line 152, in call_azan
    playsound(azan_path)
  File "C:\Users\rahma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 17, in _playsoundWin
    from random import random
ImportError: cannot import name 'random' from 'random' (d:\My stuff\mypython\Tkinter\azan caller\random.py)
```

Random.py is another file in the folder but I never used it in my main python file. This is my full code just for completeness:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Grid
import xlrd
import os
from xlrd import cellname,xldate_as_tuple,xldate_as_datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime , timedelta
from playsound import playsound
from tkinter import font




#set time and current date
current_time = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%I:%M %p")  #time.strftime("%I:%M %p")
todays_date = date.today()
month = todays_date.strftime('%m')

def current_date(todays_date):
    format_date  = todays_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    return format_date


format_date = current_date(todays_date)

#function to display current time
def display_time():
    current_time = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%I:%M %S %p")
    lbl_display_time.config(text=current_time)
    lbl_display_time.after(1000,display_time)

#function to display current date
def display_date():
    todays_date = date.today()
    month = todays_date.strftime('%m')
    format_date = todays_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    lbl_display_date.config(text=format_date)
    lbl_display_date.after(1000,display_date)






#open workbook
filename = os.path.join("D:\My stuff\mypython\Tkinter",'azan caller\prayer_timings.xlsx')
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet %s'% month)


    
def get_date(format_date):
    #number of rows in sheet
    rows = worksheet.nrows
    #get date from excel file and compare with current date
    raw_date = ''
    for i in range(-1,rows):
        raw_date = worksheet.cell_value(i,1)
        conv_date = datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(raw_date, workbook.datemode))
        excel_date = conv_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        if format_date == excel_date:
            cell_location = (i,1)
            break
    return [cell_location , excel_date]
        

def calc_countdown():
    ''' This function calculates the remaining time before the next prayer '''

    

    #converts prayer times to datetime object
    struc_prayertime_list = [datetime.strptime(i, "%I:%M %p") for i in azan_time]

    #gets the current time and converts it to datetime object
    current_time = datetime.strptime(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%I:%M:%S %p"), "%I:%M:%S %p")

    #gets the next prayer time
    nearest_time = next((i for i in struc_prayertime_list if i > current_time), datetime.strptime('01-02 04:18 AM', "%m-%d %I:%M %p"))

    #calculates the time left before next prayer, converts it to string and stores it in a variable
    time_left_text.set("{} hours {} minutes {} seconds".format(*str(nearest_time - current_time).split(":")))

    random_lbl.after(1000, calc_countdown)





#get time for different prayers
def fajr_time(cell_location):
    fajr = worksheet.cell_value(cell_location[0][0],3)
    return fajr

def zuhr_time(cell_location):
    zuhr = worksheet.cell_value(cell_location[0][0],5)
    return zuhr

def asr_time(cell_location):
    asr = worksheet.cell_value(cell_location[0][0],6)
    return asr

def maghrib_time(cell_location):
    maghrib = worksheet.cell_value(cell_location[0][0],7)
    return maghrib

def isha_time(cell_location):
    isha = worksheet.cell_value(cell_location[0][0],8)
    return isha

def update_time():
    ''' this function will run continuoulsy and its function is to keep updating the prayer times
    as the day and date changes    flow : get the correct cell_location using get_Date()  --- set prayer times
    using cell_location --- append prayer times(variables) to a list called azan_time--- return azan_time '''

    cell_location = get_date(format_date)

    
    #set prayer times
    fajr = fajr_time(cell_location)
    fajr="0"+fajr
    zuhr  = zuhr_time(cell_location)
    asr = asr_time(cell_location)
    maghrib = maghrib_time(cell_location)
    isha = isha_time(cell_location)
    
    #store prayer times in a list
    azan_time = [fajr,zuhr,asr,maghrib,isha,"3:10 PM"]

    #checks if any of the time is in PM. IF so, a '0' is added to the beginning
    azan_time.remove(zuhr)  #temporarily remove zuhr time
    for x in range(0,len(azan_time)):
        temp_time = azan_time[x]
        if temp_time[-2]+temp_time[-1] == 'PM':
            azan_time[x] = '0'+azan_time[x]

    azan_time.insert(1,zuhr) # add zuhr time back

    random_lbl.after(1000,update_time)

    return azan_time  #return azan time so it can be used



#function to check if it is time for prayer
def call_azan():
    current_time = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%I:%M %p")
    for i in range(0,len(azan_time)):
        if current_time ==  azan_time[i]:
            print("time to pray at" , azan_time[i])
            azan_path = os.path.join("azan caller","azan_sound.mp3")
            playsound(azan_path)
        else:
            continue
    random_lbl.after(1000,call_azan)



#GUI
window  = tk.Tk()
window.title("Azan Caller")
Grid.rowconfigure(window, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(window, 0, weight=1)



#set up window
height = window.winfo_screenheight()
width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
window.geometry(f'{int(width/2)}x{int(height/2)}')
frm_window = tk.Frame(window,bg="#00BFFF")
frm_window.pack(fill="both",expand=True)


# a label just to run the functions continuously after 1 second
random_lbl = tk.Label(frm_window,width=2)

#create fonts
heading_font = font.Font(family = "ShareTech",size=25,weight='bold')
subheading_font = font.Font(family="ShareTech",size=14)
body_font = font.Font(family="ShareTech",size=10,weight="bold")


# title section
frm_title = tk.Frame(frm_window,relief=tk.SOLID,borderwidth=3,bg="#000000")
frm_title.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="new",pady=(0,5))
lbl_title = tk.Label(master=frm_title, text="Azan Caller For Abu Dhabi",font=heading_font,fg="#008000")
lbl_title.pack(side='top',fill='x')

                #prayer timings table
frm_table = tk.Frame(frm_window,bg="#000000",relief=tk.SOLID,borderwidth=3)
frm_table.grid(row=1,column=0, sticky="nsew",padx=(20,20))
tbl_title  = tk.Label(frm_table,text="Today's Prayer Times",relief=tk.SOLID,font=subheading_font,borderwidth=2)
tbl_title.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=5,sticky="nsew")

#prayer names
prayer_names = ['Fajr','Zuhr','Asr','Maghrib','Isha']
for j in range(0,len(prayer_names)):
    name = prayer_names[j]
    cell = tk.Label(frm_table,text=name,relief=tk.SOLID,font=body_font,borderwidth=2)
    cell.grid(row=1,column=j,sticky="nsew")

#prayer times
azan_time = update_time()
for i in range(0,len(azan_time)):
    prayer_time = azan_time[i]
    cell_time = tk.Label(frm_table,text=prayer_time,relief=tk.SOLID,font=body_font,borderwidth=2,fg="#FF8C00")
    cell_time.grid(row=2,column=i,sticky="nsew")
        
#body section
frm_body = tk.Frame(frm_window,relief=tk.SOLID,borderwidth=5,)
frm_body.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew",pady=(10,10),padx=(20,20))

lbl_date = tk.Label(frm_body,text="Today's Date: ",font=body_font)
lbl_date.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew",pady=(0,5))
lbl_display_date = tk.Label(frm_body,font=body_font)
lbl_display_date.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="nsew",pady=(0,5))


lbl_time = tk.Label(frm_body,text="Current Time: ",font=body_font)
lbl_time.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="nsew",pady=(0,5))
lbl_display_time = tk.Label(frm_body,font=body_font)
lbl_display_time.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="nsew",pady=(0,5))

time_left_text = tk.StringVar()
lbl_countdown = tk.Label(frm_body,text="Next Prayer in : ",font=body_font)
lbl_countdown.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="nsew",pady=(0,5))
lbl_display_countdown = tk.Label(frm_body,textvariable=time_left_text,font=body_font,fg="red")
lbl_display_countdown.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="nsew",pady=(0,5))

#footer
frm_footer  = tk.Frame(frm_window,relief=tk.SOLID,borderwidth=3,bg="#000000")
frm_footer.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="sew",pady=(10,0))
lbl_footer = tk.Label(frm_footer,text="@Copyright AbdulRahman Tijani 2020",font=body_font,fg="#008000")
lbl_footer.pack(side="bottom",fill='x')


                    #make the structure resizable
#columns
for i in range(frm_window.grid_size()[0]):
    frm_window.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

for i in range(frm_table.grid_size()[0]):
    frm_table.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

for i in range(frm_body.grid_size()[0]):
    frm_body.grid_columnconfigure(i,weight=1)

#row
for i in range(frm_window.grid_size()[1]):
    frm_window.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

for i in range(frm_table.grid_size()[1]):
    frm_table.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)


for i in range(frm_body.grid_size()[1]):
    frm_body.grid_rowconfigure(i,weight=1)



#run functions
display_date()
display_time()
update_time()
call_azan()
calc_countdown()



window.mainloop()
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Your local `random.py` will override the built-in random module.  Avoid using built-in module names as local script name.  Rename the local `random.py` to other name.

Comment: Yah my mistake. Now its working although when the mp3 file is playing, the GUI freezes and so if i try to close it, the application crashes. I guess this is because while the mp3 file is playing, the window cannot be updated? If so, is there anything I can do to fix it

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve].

Comment: @BryanOakley  Yes that was because i wasn't sure where the problem was. But the problem that i had when i asked the question was solved but now i have a new problem. Do I ask a new question or can I edit this current one

Comment: When you aren't sure where the problem is, remove a block of code and see if the problem is still there. If it is, you know the problem wasn't in that block of code. For example, it seems highly likely the problem isn't in `asr_time`, or `isha_time`. Continue doing that until removing a block of code makes the problem go away. Now you know which block of code had the problem.

Comment: it wud b good to post as a new Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is because you have a file in your directory called `random.py` which is being imported here and python is reading that in and not the `random` module, so try not to name your script files as same as the module names.

And instead of using playsound, why dont you try the `pygame` module for playing sounds. Refer how to [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html)